# Count windows that contain a determined word

Tags: macos, window, applescript, counting, contain

I've always counted windows using this command:

```
set windowsnumber to count windows
```

Now I'm in the need of counting windows that contain a specific string.

E.g. If a process has 5 windows opened (windows "A", "B", "A", "C", "D"), I need something like "count windows that contains "A" in their title", should return 2 in this example.

Is this feasible with applescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `whose` filter :

```
set windowsnumber to count (windows whose title contains "A")
```